# How to load parquet files from Azure Data Lake Gen2/Azure Blob Storage to Dedicated pool using dbt?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-synapse, dbt, azure-data-lake-gen2

I'm using dbt-synapse: https://github.com/dbt-msft/dbt-synapse
I want to load my parquet file from Azure Data Lake Gen2/Azure Blob Storage to the dedicated pool in Azure Synapse.
I tried to use

```
{{ config(materialized='table') }}
with my_table as (
    SELECT
        TOP 100 *
    FROM
        OPENROWSET(
            BULK 'myparquetfile_url',
            FORMAT = 'PARQUET'
        ) AS [result]
)

select * from my_table
```

but no luck.

It shows this error

```
('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Parse error at line: 7, column: 9: Incorrect syntax near 'OPENROWSET'. (103010) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

So, how can I load parquets file from blob storage to dedicated pool using dbt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately `OPENROWSET` isn't supported in Azure Synapse Analytics.

There is a GitHub repository which you can use to load external tables using dbt. This you can use as an alternative.

https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables

Supported database:

- Redshift (Spectrum)
- Snowflake
- BigQuery
- Spark
- Synapse
- Azure SQL